# raspicam and uv4l-server as netcam on Motion

Tags: raspicam, motion, uv4l

Setup:

- Raspberry Pi 2 B
- Raspberry Pi Camera Board - PiNoir
- uv4l-server and uv4l with uv4l_raspicam driver @ 640x480 px
- Motion by lavrsen.dk

I am doing live streaming with uv4l-server at `http://raspberryip:8080/stream/video.mjpeg`. This mjpeg stream works like a charme.
On a second Pi I  want to detect motion but Motion always gives me pixeled images / see below.

```
# motion.conf for Motion on a second Pi 
# <also tried on a second ubuntu environment 
# with the same pixel-crashed images below>
...
netcam_url http://raspberryip:8080/stream/video.mjpeg
...
```

Looking at Motion's internal webcam server (default port 8081) I am observing the same crashed images as saved by Motion to the dir_target

Any clues why despite viewing `http://raspberryip:8080/stream/video.mjpeg` directly streamed by Pi No.1 is working, Motion running on Pi No.2 (or even running on Ubuntu) is giving these pixel- and colour-crashed images?

**I appreciate any hints..**

Why is the live stream by uv4l-server fine, but Motion's output/live webserver is not?

[image: image that Motion is giving me - although the uv4l-server gives a working mjpeg stream] [image]